# Custom axis tick marks and labels using discrete scales in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I want to make a plot in R showing mean values and confidence intervals for a set of variables. The variables should be grouped in two sections in the plot.

Here is some example data:

```
set.seed (110)
mean_vals <- runif (10, min = 7, max = 15)
lower_conf <- mean_vals - runif (10, min = 0.5, max = 3)
upper_conf <- mean_vals + runif (10, min = 0.5, max = 3)
var_names <- factor (c (paste0("variable", LETTERS[1:9]), "longVariableJ"),
                     levels = c ("longVariableJ", paste0("variable", LETTERS[9:1]) )
                     )

plot_data <- data.frame (variable = var_names, mean = mean_vals, lower = lower_conf, upper = upper_conf)
```

Without sections, the plot would be something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot (data = plot_data, 
        mapping = aes(x = mean, xmin = lower, xmax = upper, 
                      y = variable)
                                  ) + 
    geom_errorbarh (height = 0.1) +
    geom_point (shape = 21) +
    labs (x = "Estimate", y = "") +
    theme_bw()
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

My approach to include sections did not work out so far. I tried the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_data_extended <- plot_data %>% 
    add_row (.before = 5, variable = "section2") %>%
    add_row (.before = 5, variable = "") %>%
    add_row (.before = 1, variable = "section1")

plot_data_extended$variable <- factor (plot_data_extended$variable,
                                       levels = rev (plot_data_extended$variable))


ggplot (data = plot_data_extended, 
        mapping = aes(x = mean, xmin = lower, xmax = upper, 
                      y = variable)
                                  ) + 
    geom_errorbarh (height = 0.1) +
    geom_point (shape = 21) +
    labs (x = "Estimate", y = "") +
    theme_bw()
```

This gives me this plot:

[image]

This goes in the rigth direction, but:

- I want to omit the tick marks for rows which do not conatain data for drawing points and whisker - that is, the "section" rows and the empty row.
- I want "*section1*" and "*section2*" to be *Italic* and
- I want "*section1*" and "*section2*" to left-align with the longest variable name (here "longVariableJ").

I don't know if there is a better apporach than adding rows to my plot_data dataframe. And if there is no more elegant way, I struggle really hard customizing the tick marks and tick labels. I tried editing the dataframe further, adding e.g. a column indicating whether to draw or not tick marks (and accordingly, align tick labels left), but I had no success. I found no function similar to this imaginary function: `if (plot_data_extended$omit_tickmark == 1) {omit_tickmark (), leftaline_ticklabel (), italic_ticklabel ()}` or similar.
So:

- how can I tell R to omit specific tick marks
- how can I tell R to left-align specific labels with the longest label of a plot and
- put these in *italic*?

Help is very much appreciated - also, if onbly one of these issues gets adressed.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you don't want to use facet plots? it does the sectioning for you while not requiring to set manual parameters except for the groups you want to separate:

```
plot_data <- mutate(plot_data, section = c(rep("section1", 4), rep("section2", 6)))

ggplot (data = plot_data, 
        mapping = aes(x = mean, xmin = lower, xmax = upper, 
                      y = variable)) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(section), ncol=1, scales="free_y") +
  geom_errorbarh (height = 0.1) +
  geom_point (shape = 21) +
  labs (x = "Estimate", y = "") +
  theme_bw()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: The only reason is some kind of "style guideline" I need to follow. All should appear as one single plot in the end.

Comment: I try to find out whether there is a chance to make a faceted plot that *looks* like a single plot. I'd need to get rid of all background colours and lines between the single panels and also get panels that differ in hight according to the respective group size...

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the ticks marks and making the section italic could be easily achieved by passing vectors to the arguments of the `theme` elements. But be aware that this is a bit hacky and not officially supported and hence you will get a warning about that. Aligning the section text with the longest label is a different thing. At least I have not found a perfect solution and the best I could come with already requires to switch to `ggtext::element_markdown` but still requires to manually set the horizontal alignment, i.e. for your example data setting `hjust=1.5` for the section text seems to work fine:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data = plot_data_extended,
  mapping = aes(
    x = mean, xmin = lower, xmax = upper,
    y = variable
  )
) +
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0.1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  labs(x = "Estimate", y = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .5 * rev(c(0, rep(1, 4), 0, 0, rep(1, 6)))
    ),
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(
      face = rev(c("bold.italic", rep("plain", 4), "plain", "bold.italic", rep("plain", 6))),
      hjust = rev(c(1.5, rep(1, 4), 1, 1.5, rep(1, 6)))
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This gets already close to what I was looking for. However, it get's really tricky when the "sections" are named differently with differing string length; I'd have to manually check what settings of 'hjust' work for all label elements. Strange: if I set 'hjust = 0' for all elements, they get perfectly left-alined. However, mixing different 'hjust' - values yields rather strange results. I really tried hard and messed around a lot with the hjust and also the margin parameter - without success. If there only was a good way to "nudge" single tick labels, I could do it, I suppose.